# Using latest Code Sign Certificate in build scripts to sign algorithms sha1, sha384, sha256

Tags: windows, executable, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

The new certificate arrived on usb stick ( it seems IExplorer is no more used ) but it does not seem to any more support all algorithms; also the signtool no more accepts the pwd as cmd line parameter, so its not handy to sign with multiple algorithms multiple files any more.

My script to sign the win executable is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /a %1
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com /td sha1 /fd sha1 /a %1
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com /td sha384 /fd sha384 /a %1
```

What algorithms are needed nowadays for maximum compatibility with OSes?

Is it enough to use just sha384?